# Java Comparing two strings throws still true

Tags: java

Hy,  I have a problem when I'm comparing two Strings wich are null

```
public void run(){
    System.out.println(properties.readConfig("port.cfg"));
    String lport = "";
    String lasd = "";
    File fport = null;
    File fasd = null;
    try {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("port.cfg"));//this (if file doent exist) will create it
        BufferedWriter witer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("asd.cfg"));//this (if file doent exist) will create it
        writer.close();
        witer.close();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("port.cfg"));
        BufferedReader rader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("asd.cfg"));
            lport = reader.readLine();
            lasd = rader.readLine();
        reader.close();
        rader.close();
        fasd = new File("asd.cfg");
        fport = new File("port.cfg");
        commands.print(String.valueOf(StringUtils.equals(lasd, lport)));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        temp = InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString().split("/");
        settings.myIp = temp[1];
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
    if(StringUtils.equals(lasd, lport)){//here is the problem
        properties.saveConfig("port.cfg", "8795");
        settings.port = properties.readConfig("port.cfg");
        commands.print("Current port is: " + settings.port);
    }else{
        settings.port = properties.readConfig("port.cfg");
    }



}
```

When I run the program first time problem part throws true and writes in to the file `port.cfg` a port and this port could be changed by a user (this is good), but when I run the program second time it will throw again `true` and rewrite the port (and this is bad because text in the file `port.cfg (String lport)` isn't same as in the file `asd.cfg (String lasd)`.`commands` and `settings` are my classes.`StrungUtils` class is from `apache.common.lang`

Edit:

I have tried: `lport == lasd, lport == null && lasd == null`

Comment: Your question makes no sense - the value `true` can't be *thrown* - only exceptions can. What do you actually mean? If you mean "`StringUtils.equals(null, null)` returns true" then you should say so... Note that I suspect your problem could be shown in about 5 lines of code rather than 40... It doesn't help that we have no idea which `StringUtils` class you're talking about, either...

Comment: i have posted whole code because i know some of you guys might wnat to see whole code because you might want to know where from is lport and lasd and i marked down where is the problem

Comment: Didn't understand your question. Are you asking why those two strings are null or why the if condition returning true when both args are null ?

Comment: No, we don't typically want to see whole reams of unrelated code. It's much better to provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, and a bit of context in text. Most of this code is entirely irrelevant. Note that if you *had* posted a short but complete program to start with, it would be obvious that you were using Apache Commons to start with.

Comment: ok, ill ask you on one thing, when i use:
File file1 = new File("port.cfg");//contain 8950,
File file2 = new File("asd.cfg");//empty file,
boolean isTwoEqual = FileUtils.contentEquals(file1, file2);

Then it still throws true, why? I've read that if one of these is null it will throw false.

Comment: Please stop using the word "throws" when you mean "returns" - *terminology matters*. You're now asking about an entirely different API... and "an empty file" isn't the same as "a null reference".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not know how `StringUtils.equals()` is implemented. For example, this `throws` a `RuntimeException`:

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String a = null;
        String b = null;

        System.out.println(StringUtils.equals(a, b));
    }
}

class StringUtils {

    public static final boolean equals(String a, String b) {
        return a.equals(b);
    }
}
```

This, on the other hand, `returns true`

```
public static final boolean equals(String a, String b) {
    if(a == null && b == null) {
        return true;
    }
    else if(a == null || b == null) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return a.equals(b);
    }
}
```

Without knowing the implementation of `StringUtils.equals()`, we cannot help you. Either write your own `equals()` method, as I have done here in two different ways, or learn the API you are including in your programs and use them accordingly.

Comment: ok, but when i read 1st line ( wich is only line in files) from port.cfg(contain 8975) to lport and from asd.cfg(empty file) to lasd, and comapre them with StringUtils.equals it still returns true why? when lport = 8975 and lasd = null (when i print in to the console lasd it returns null)

Comment: Are you printing out your values after you have read them into the program to know for sure what the values actually are? You may have both values as a space or null or god knows what...Do this:  System.out.println("[" + a + "][" + b + "]"); and tell me what you see printed from Console

Comment: [null][null] I see some problem here because even when i write something in to the file i still recive [null][null]

Comment: OK, your first goal is to get values into your variables. Once that works, you can worry about your other issues

Comment: I think i fixed it , ther was a problem with variables because (and i dont know why) when i put them out of the try/catch cycle then it works :D can you tell me why ?

Comment: Not sure for your case, but in future don't assume anything about your values until you actually know. Use that little trick I showed you to see if there's a space or null in there (as opposed to an empty String or some other value)

Answer (score 2):

```
 StringUtils.equals(null, null) = true
```

For both `null` values  `StringUtils` will return `true`.You should add `null` check before `StringUtils` [`equals`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#equals%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

```
if(lasd != null && lport != null && StringUtils.equals(lasd, lport)) {
   //...
}
```